# Вывод текста после символа = и перед ;

Tags: массивы, php, строки

Всем привет, имею такие данные:

```
LI_site = 'idwm.biz';
LI_month_hit = 338632;
LI_month_vis = 11129;
LI_week_hit = 73786;
LI_week_vis = 3518;
LI_day_hit = 10028;
LI_day_vis = 750;
LI_today_hit = 9516;
LI_today_vis = 730;
LI_online_hit = 168;
LI_online_vis = 20;
```

Нужно с помощью php запихнуть все значения(всё что после = и перед ;) в массив, и чтобы потом можно было написать например так:

```
echo $somevariable[1];
```

И вывелось значение 338632, я никак не могу решить эту задачу, помогите пожалуйста(

Comment: Эти данные у вас хранятся где? В файле?

Comment: По интернет адресу: http://counter.yadro.ru/values?site=idwm.biz

Comment: имеенно от первго индекса ? 

    $variable['LI_month_hit']

не подойдет ?

Comment: Нет это я к примеру, я просто хочу спарсить данные с той страницы, загнать их в массив, и из массива с помощью индекса уже выводить эти данные.

Comment: Исключительно с целью посмеяться:

`print_r(json_decode('{"' .str_replace(array("\r", "\n", ';', ' = ', "'"), array('', '', '", "', '" : "', ""), trim(trim(file_get_contents('http://counter.yadro.ru/values?site=idwm.biz')), ';')) . '"}'));`


;-)

Comment: Чтобы посмеяться еще сильнее:  
http://ideone.com/mA4UGm

Comment: Товарищи, спасибо огромное, выручили :) Но это рег. выражение 

    preg_replace("/=\\s*(.*?)\\s*;/es", "\$result[]=\"$1\"", $text);

Меня пугает) И вообще регулярки, никак понять их не могу :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://counter.yadro.ru/values?site=idwm.biz';

if($data = file_get_contents($url))
    $result = parse_ini_string($data);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($result, true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, этот вариант подошёл, да ещё и легкий без регулярных выражений :)